# Prevent listview from adding blank subitem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `listview` in which the columns are dynamically created depending on the number of available subjects. When I create a new `ListViewItem` it automatically adds a blank `subitem` to the `listview`. Since the columns are dynamically created, the subitems are displaced. This is how I have done it.

```
foreach(int id in stud)
{
ListViewItem gtb = new ListViewItem();
foreach(int sname in subj)
{
    gtb.SubItems.Add(value1);
    gtb.SubItems.Add(value2);
    gtb.SubItems.Add(value3);
}
gtb.SubItems.Add(value4);
listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { gtb });
}
```

I know that adding the `value1` to new `ListViewItem(value1)` would fix this but i have another `subitem` which is outside of the `foreach loop`. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: try to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx). Ex: If (value2 != null) then add.

Comment: the values are not null hold on let me revise the question

Comment: What is happening is that SubItem[0] is actually the parent ListViewItem since you are not populating it, it is empty.

Comment: have you tried `gtb.Text = value1`?

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'if' statement that will check the length of each value then if the length is greater than zero you add the item to 'gtb'.

Comment: its not the null values that i want to filter out. its the blank subitem that is added on each listviewitem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `String[]`, use it to collect your subitems, then create a new `ListViewItem` using that:

```
String[] subItems = new String[subj.Count + 1];  //add however many extras you need in place of 1
for (int j = 0; j < subj.Count; j++)
    subItems[j] = subj[j];
//add whatever else to the array you want...
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(subItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried manually adding a new column which has a 0 width and it works just fine.

Comment: In this case "works" simply means hidden.  Better to add a proper item than to hack the display.  You'll pay for it later when you try to reference sub-items, always have to remember to ignore one.